# java : I am getting only one element while parsing the values

Tags: java

when this program is run , i am getting only one name , instead of two 
That is the output is Pavan only

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Work {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        User user1 = new User();
        User user2 = new User();

        user1.setName("Pavan");
        user2.setName("Palla");

        List userItems = new ArrayList();
        userItems.add(user1);
        userItems.add(user2);

        UserlistItem[] userlistitem = new UserlistItem[userItems.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < userItems.size(); i++) {

            User user = (User) userItems.get(i);

            userlistitem[i] = new UserlistItem();

            userlistitem[i].setUser(user);

        }

        Userlist userlistm = new Userlist();
        userlistm.setUserlistItem(userlistitem);

        UserlistItem[] ravi = userlistm.getUserlistItem();

        Userlists lists = new Userlists();

        lists.setUserlist(new Userlist[] { userlistm });

        Userlist[] main = lists.getUserlist();

        for (int i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Pavan"
                    + main[i].getUserlistItem()[i].getUser().getName());
        }


}

public class User {

     private String      name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


public class UserlistItem {
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    } 


}



import java.io.Serializable;

public class Userlist {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserlistItem[] getUserlistItem() {
        return UserlistItem;
    }

    public void setUserlistItem(UserlistItem[] userlistItem) {
        UserlistItem = userlistItem;
    }

    private String id;
    private UserlistItem[] UserlistItem;

}



public class Userlists {

    private Userlist[] userlist;

    public Userlist[] getUserlist() {
        return userlist;
    }

    public void setUserlist(Userlist[] userlist) {
        this.userlist = userlist;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add some simple debugging `println` statements so you can check you have the expected 2 items throughout this maze of adding and removing stuff from lists, arrays etc. Please try to narrow down the problem a bit before posting...

Comment: Ever consider replacing `UserLists`, `UserList`, and `UserListItem` with just:  `List<User>` and `List<List<User>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why don't you debug your code by putting a breakpoint to the line where the printing happens? In the 2nd for loop of your main method, main.length is 1. Change the loop to the code below, it will be done. But your code is confusing, I'm not sure how you will track more objects of your defined classes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < main[0].getUserlistItem().length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Pavan"
            + main[0].getUserlistItem()[i].getUser().getName());
}
```